# Integrating my web app authentication with sites like facebook?

Tags: authentication, authorization, openid

I have a web application where user is authenticated against credentials in DB. Now a days i see the sites incuding SO that allows
users not create new credentials but use the existing credentials with sites like facebook,gmail,yahoo etc.

Can anybody brief how it is done technically so that it helps me to understand should i proceed in this direction?

I came across that it is done using OpenID but that is just protocol. If i want to allow my site to use facebook credentials, do i need to purchase
some OpenId implementing product and contact sites like facebook,gmail etc.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/v2.2

Comment: actually i want to get brief how it is done technically?

Comment: There are examples in the documentation.  Other sites which also provide that service tend to also provide documentation.  Generally the prevailing standard these days is OAuth, and a lot of web application frameworks have built-in support to assist with that.